# HTML single page with No scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a webpage. The thing I need is the webpage should be of fixed size based on the user window size,  like we don't need to scroll down to see something. I can change it to a particular height, but the thing is when resizing the browser window it again contains the scroll option since the image size [image: single webpage[![][1]]
[image]

In the above shown figure the first image get oversized, and hence it shows empty space instead of  responsive
In the second one  the user window get reduced in size hence their shows a scrollview , the thing is i want it to get flexible. for varying the window size varies the height of the div instead of showing scrolling options. Can any one help me in this?

thanks for the answers guys!Also answer if In case I want 3 columns of equal width and fixed height with the same no scrolling option

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you create jsfiddle link?

Comment: " I can change it to a particular height " do the same on window resize, use window.resize event

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your code css/html that tries to achieve this?

Comment: Where's your code? Please read up on providing a [mcve].

Answer (score 6):

You can use the "new" css units **vh** and **vw** which are relative to the size of the viewport and it's quite supported right now. Example:

```
.row {
  height:33.3vh;
}
```

See [this pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LxmWzm) that I've made for see it in action.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is the VH (viewport height). There's a fiddle where you can see it working:

```
.yourdivs{
    height:33vh;
    background-color:red;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
```

[jsFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gianemi2/mh6sn7a8/)

From w3school:

**CSS Units**

**vh**: Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport.

**Viewport**: the browser window size. If the viewport is 50cm wide, 1vw = 0.5cm.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function setHeight() {
    windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
    $('#divImage').css('min-height', windowHeight);
  };
  console.log($('#divImage').height());
  setHeight();
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#divImage {
  height: auto;
}
img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divImage">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1600x900">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Look at "meta" and css-style of body](http://jsbin.com/nevala/edit?html,css,js,output)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1">
```

and CSS:

```
body{
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
body>div{
  max-height: 33.3vh;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```